# 404 error on custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, 404-error

I know this has been asked a million times but I am pulling out the little hair I have!

I have a custom post type called case-study (case-study.php and then linked in functions), a file called single-case-study.php and setup a post called test but I get a 404 when I go to *website/case-study/test*. I have tryed `flush_rewrite_rules();` in my *functions.php* and after `register_post_type('case-study' ,$args );`, I have tried goingt to permalinks in the settings and saving and I have tried changing some of the things in the post register such as hierarchical or has_archive.

I have tried disabling all plugins, basically I have tried everything on this website [How to Fix 404](http://dreamdare.org/tips-tricks/how-to-fix-wordpress-custom-post-type-permalink-404-error/) and anything I could find on here. Does anyone know of anything else that could be casuing this?

Here is my register_post_type:

```
$args = array(
    'label'              => 'Case Study',
    'public'             => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui'            => true,
    'query_var'          => false,
    'capability_type'    => 'page',
    'hierarchical'       => true,
    'has_archive'        => false,
    'rewrite'            => array('slug' => 'case-study', 'with_front' => false),
    'supports'           => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
    'menu_position'      => 31
);
register_post_type('case-study' ,$args );
```

Comment: Hi Snookian. Your problem might be the 'query_var' arg, try removing it, or setting it to 'post_type'?

Comment: OMG! THANK YOU! MY SAVIOUR! Out of curiosity what does that actually do?

Comment: @PedroCoitinho write an answer ;)

Comment: Yeah write an answer. I just looked it up at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/. Had no idea that 'query_var' stops it loading at the slug. Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing `'query_var'=> false` solved this. Thanks to @PedroCoitinho

Comment: Make sure to refresh permalinks after removing the query_var config.